# Mapbox data with google sheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, mapbox, google-forms

I am working to develop a crowdsourcing website that takes input from google forms and displays this information on a map. I am working with mapbox and am looking for a way to get the data points in my google spreadsheet (with lat/long info) to automatically show up on the map. Any tips would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a similar project.

I 'published' my google spreadsheet: `file > Publish To Web`.
You should get a popup window with a URL for your sheet:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[your ID here]/pubhtml`

Once you have the `ID` you can use it on your website:

```
 // ID of the Google Spreadsheet
 var spreadsheetID = 'fakeExample';

 // Make sure it is public or set to `Anyone with link can view` 
 var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/od6/public/values?alt=json";

 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {

     var entry = data.feed.entry;

     $(entry).each(function(){
        //do stuff with each entry in your spreadsheet
        // for example, build a GeoJSON object with your lat/lons or add an individual marker

        // ex: add the 'country' column to the `results` box
        $('.results').prepend('<h2>'+this.gsx$country.$t+'</h2>);
     });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use any mapbox js map [with omnivore](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markers-from-csv/), for example. 
The form results go in a google sheet -  geocode it automatically with some script - publish the sheet to the web with results in csv - the coordinates are pulled automatically to the map which updates upon loading.